# Capistrano deployment with Bitbucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, bitbucket, capistrano3

When I try to execute Capistrano deployment script to deploy my project from bitbucket.org it fails while executing following command

```
$ RBENV_ROOT=/path/to/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/appname/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@bitbucket.org:username/project.git
```

But the same command works fine when I ssh into the deployment machine and execute it manually

Capistrano Trace:

```
    ** Execute git:check
INFO [f938a643] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@131.103.20.167:username/project.git on 172.10.0.111
DEBUG [f938a643] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=/path/to/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/project/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@bitbucket.org:username/project.git )
DEBUG [f938a643]    conq: repository access denied.
DEBUG [f938a643]    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
DEBUG [f938a643]
DEBUG [f938a643]    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
DEBUG [f938a643]    and the repository exists.
cap aborted!
```

Deployment Server output:

```
$ RBENV_ROOT=/path/to/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.5 GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/appname/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@bitbucket.org:username/project.git
ee4088b33b5151536d9783c80c40eec3f48f86df    refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually indicates an SSH key issue. Make sure that the private key which you have associated with BitBucket is in `~/.ssh/id_(dsa|rsa)` and is chmod 600.

Comment: thanks @will_in_wi. Yes permission was the issue. changed it to 600 and now it works fine.

Comment: Very glad I could help!